# Putting JSON results into a php array

Tags: php, json, parsing, search-engine

I have the following  array

```
Array
(
[responseData] => Array
      (
         [results] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [GsearchResultClass] => GwebSearch
                        [unescapedUrl] => http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JH_(hash_function)
                        [url] => http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JH_(hash_function)
                        [visibleUrl] => en.wikipedia.org
                        [cacheUrl] => http://www.google.com/search?q=cache:jxOefvJSQXUJ:en.wikipedia.org
                        [title] => JH (hash function) - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
                        [titleNoFormatting] => JH (hash function) - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
                        [content] => JH is a cryptographic hash function submitted to the NIST hash function   competition by Hongjun Wu. Though chosen as one of the five finalists of the   competition ...
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [GsearchResultClass] => GwebSearch
                        [unescapedUrl] => http://www.jhaudio.com/
                        [url] => http://www.jhaudio.com/
                        [visibleUrl] => www.jhaudio.com
                        [cacheUrl] => http://www.google.com/search?q=cache:rO6NylpvTx8J:www.jhaudio.com
                        [title] => JH Audio: Custom In-Ear Monitors | In Ear Monitor
                        [titleNoFormatting] => JH Audio: Custom In-Ear Monitors | In Ear Monitor
                        [content] => Custom In-Ear Monitors by JHAudio - manufacturers of premium custom in ear   monitors. JH Audio's products are a direct result of 25 years of live audio mixing ...
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [GsearchResultClass] => GwebSearch
                        [unescapedUrl] => http://www.jhaudio.com/collection/jha-pro-music-products
                        [url] => http://www.jhaudio.com/collection/jha-pro-music-products
                        [visibleUrl] => www.jhaudio.com
                        [cacheUrl] => http://www.google.com/search?q=cache:YY9q-E00yKkJ:www.jhaudio.com
                        [title] => JHA Pro Music Products | Custom In-Ear Monitors by JH Audio
                        [titleNoFormatting] => JHA Pro Music Products | Custom In-Ear Monitors by JH Audio
                        [content] => JHA Pro Music Products by JHAudio - manufacturers of premium custom in ear   monitors. JH Audio's products are a direct result of 25 years of live audio mixing ...
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [GsearchResultClass] => GwebSearch
                        [unescapedUrl] => http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JsQN3yZjRCI
                        [url] => http://www.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DJsQN3yZjRCI
                        [visibleUrl] => www.youtube.com
                        [cacheUrl] => http://www.google.com/search?q=cache:Dk4oETmQLNEJ:www.youtube.com
                        [title] => monta equina zagalo de j.h x gitana de la fortuna - YouTube
                        [titleNoFormatting] => monta equina zagalo de j.h x gitana de la fortuna - YouTube
                        [content] => Mar 5, 2010 ... caballos de exposicion en la modalidad de trote y galope, fecha de monta 1 de   febrero de 2010....
                    )

            )
```

I'm trying to parse it in php using a foreach loop so the url, title and content will be shown. However I can't seem to parse the code properly. The code below gives me an error that 'responsedata' isin't recognisied.

```
foreach($json as value)

echo $value [responsedata];
```

When I leave it at echo $value, it gives me the number 200, which is the value of responsestatus. When I try

```
foreach( $json =>url => title => content as $value)
```

it won't recognise the '=' sign.

Any ideas?? I'm not overly familiar with JSON or php if you havn't gotten that from the post:)

TIA

Answer (score 1):

FTR, what you posted is a native array, not a "json array", try this:

```
$rawArray = get_results_somehow();

// Flatten the array to make it easier to work with
$results = $rawArray['responseData']['results'];

foreach ($results as $result) {

    // Should now see the expected values
    var_dump($result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That data is already in array form. You need to iterate on $array['responseData']['results'] like this.

```
$arr = $array['responseData']['results'];

foreach($arr as $k){
   echo $k['url'];
   echo $k['title'];
   echo $k['content'];
}
```